# Windows 10 Boot Camp shuts down and boots into macOS overnight

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Only when I wake up in the morning I find my MacBook Pro 16” in Catalina. At night the computer is in Windows 10. This happens only overnight. Throughout the day my computer remains in windows 10. Even whilst asleep. Is there something causing the computer to shut down?

Answer (score 1):

Windows is probably rebooting on its own, and macOS is currently set as your default operating system on boot.

You can make Windows the default in macOS by opening System Preferences > Startup Disk and clicking on Bootcamp. Mine has macOS as the default boot:

[image: Startup disk screenshot on System Preferences]

Or on Windows, by opening the Bootcamp preferences, clicking the Bootcamp drive then clicking [Ok] or [Apply]:

[image: Bootcamp preferences screenshot]

If you want Windows to stop automatically rebooting it's a bit harder to do, because that's a Microsoft thing, they apparently like to reboot regardless of what you're doing even after telling them you are working and can't update now.

[Here are instructions to disable automatic updates on Windows](https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Automatic-Updates-in-Windows-10). You will then be able to update manually when you want, but after I think 30~60 days or so without updating, your Windows will force you to update.
[Alternative link to disable automatic updates.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-stop-updates-installing-automatically-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows set as the default boot source in macOS's System Prefs > Startup Disk?

If not, then Windows could be initiating the reboot for its own housekeeping purposes [which it tends to do a lot], but macOS is taking precedence at the actual reboot.